How to ensure the type of a file uploaded to s3 using presigned post and posted as a form data?
I am implementing an endpoint in an API that let's the user create a presigned url to post content into our s3 bucket.
I want to add a condition or anything similar to restrict the type of the file uploaded. It mainly needs to be multimedia ( 'video/<>', 'image/<>', etc). I also want to be able to change it depending on the user or the media name, to ensure the user uploads the desired media.
I have tried adding a condition like this:
conditions = [
  ['eq', "$Content-Type", "video/mp4"],
]

s3_client = boto3.client("s3")

response = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(
                bucket_name,
                object_name,
                Fields=fields,
                Conditions=conditions,
                ExpiresIn=expiration_seconds,
            )


The creation of the presigned url and fields is correct.
But when I try to upload the content using a POST request I get the following error from s3:
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$file/type", "(binary)"]</Message><RequestId>0W4G14FZD8FTMXX9</RequestId><HostId>SF1+p7uCHg985CEiADPwcuim+l2rECOXIgmhlDAcY3jEjpKF0g55sSTRn66P12YI6Jya1HtrHFA=</HostId></Error>'

This happens because I'm forced to do the POST using multipart/form-data format.
If I add a header like this: headers = {'Content-Type': mime_type}
I get the following error:
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Error><Code>PreconditionFailed</Code><Message>At least one of the pre-conditions you specified did not hold</Message><Condition>Bucket POST must be of the enclosure-type multipart/form-data</Condition><RequestId>BD53K5K11MZ3J5WY</RequestId><HostId>SohKyIshtXiwaTT7ndN0Tioj/kePbza7SJ8VcKbDydCleELsKb/DIbHu3+VGyG3tvOjYEqS4dR8=</HostId></Error>'

If the form data also contains a key 'Content-type' with the correct type, the file is successfully uploaded but the type is not really checked from the file but from the request form params.
I wonder if is there any way to get properties from the file itself or to check it's type using conditions or fields. Hope someone has been able to fix a similar error. Thanks!
